# Problems uploading big wars to glassfish

Tags: web-applications, glassfish

So our war file recently ballooned from about 55MB to over 100MB. At which point, deploy by upload in admin stopped working. Deploy from the command line and deploy from the local filesystem still work. Experimenting, we've determined that the failure point is somewhere between 95 - 100 MB, as in at 95MB war deploys successfully while a 100 MB doesn't.

The failure is uninformative.

1. Go to the admin app
2. Click on "Web Applications" in the tree
3. Click on "Deploy..."
4. Select "Packaged file to be uploaded to the server" if it isn't already
5. Click "Browse..." and select the war file
6. Click "Ok"

At which point is churns for a couple of seconds and then returns to the deploy screen as if nothing happened. The logs have nothing out of the ordinary in them either. This happens whether the server is on our local machines or not.

All of our QA procedures use this deployment method, so switching to the alternatives would be a big pain. And the clients might raise a stink as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is a configurable limit. There's a thread in the [Glassfish forum](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=319318&#319318) about 100MB EAR files.

Following the thread's advise, I modified `$GLASSFISH_HOME/lib/install/applications/adminGUI/adminGUI_war/WEB-INF/web.xml`, increasing the `maxSize` param to 200000000.

```
    <filter-name>UploadFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>maxSize</param-name>
            <param-value>100000000</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Comment: Pretty hard to find because there's nothing in logs.
Thanks for answering your question :)